# how to reverse small lists within a main list without messing the small lists order?

Tags: python, list, tuples

The problem is that I am given a list:
`[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]`.
I am to reverse each lists within the main list, then print this:
`[[4, 3, 2, 1], [8, 7, 6, 5], [12, 11, 10, 9], [16, 15, 14, 13]]`.

First I did the below as it seemed the simplest:

```
l1=[1,2,3,4]
l2=[5,6,7,8]
l3=[9,10,11,12]
l4=[13,14,15,16]

l=[]
l.append(l1)
l.append(l2)
l.append(l3)
l.append(l4)
print(l)

list=[]

l1.reverse()
l2.reverse()
l3.reverse()
l4.reverse()

list.append(l1)
list.append(l2)
list.append(l3)
list.append(l4)
print(list)
```

But it doesn't involve the main list so it's not a viable answer.

Then I tried to put the groups of 4 as strings/int then reverse it, but it didn't recognise the content inside the bracket as integers.

```
list1 = ['1, 2, 3, 4', '5, 6, 7, 8', '9, 10, 11, 12', '13, 14, 15, 16']
list2 = []

for x in list1:
list2.append(int(x[::-1]))

print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Then lastly I tried the below, but multiple integers seem to be too many elements for `[x]`.

```
list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]

print(list)

NewList= [x for [x] in list]
x.reverse()

print(NewList)
```

Comment: why not `[sub_l[::-1] for sub_l in lst]` ?

Comment: Why not `for sublist in l: sublist.reverse()`? Not every `for` loop needs to be replaced with a list comprehension, *especially* when you don't need a new list.

Comment: Stop using python built-ins as variable names. As soon as you use `list =` you break the `list` built-in.

Comment: I sliced the list into sublists like this: 
{list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]] 
sub_l1=list[0]
sub_l2=list[1]
sub_l3=list[2]
sub_l4=list[3]}
Then reversed them all and appended into a new list. Guess this works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
my_list = []

l1 = [1,2,3,4]
l2 = [5,6,7,8]
l3 = [9,10,11,12]
l4 = [13,14,15,16]

l1.reverse()
l2.reverse()
l3.reverse()
l4.reverse()

my_list.append(l1)
my_list.append(l2)
my_list.append(l3)
my_list.append(l4)

print(my_list)
```

Comment: it does work but the main list should be used for functions.

Answer (score 0):

I made a way where I access the smaller lists:

```
my_list = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]

l1 = my_list[0]
l2 = my_list[1]
l3 = my_list[2]
l4 = my_list[3]

l1.reverse()
l2.reverse()
l3.reverse()
l4.reverse()

my_list.append(l1)
my_list.append(l2)
my_list.append(l3)
my_list.append(l4)

print(my_list)
```